# How can I nest viewports in SDL2

Tags: c++, nested, viewport, sdl-2

I have a large viewport on the right side of the screen (here "Layers"), and I render a rectangle inside that viewport ("actorRect"). Then, I set viewport to actorRect and try to SDL_RenderDrawLines a stickman in the rectangle.

The stickman gets rendered way over on the left side of the screen, as if it were using the plain x,y coordinates of the ActorRect.

[image: illustration]

In the above picture, I circled my stickman and drew an arrow pointing at actorRect. (actorRect is only green here so I can tell where it is. Later it's gonna be some other color, or like an outline or something, idk yet).

I want that stickman to render inside that rectangle.

Here's a code snippet:

```
//vector mStickmanIcon = {/*...a bunch of points...*/};
SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &Layers);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 200,250,165,255);
SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &actorRect);
SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &actorRect);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0,0,0,255);
SDL_RenderDrawLines(gRenderer, mStickmanIcon.data(), mStickmanIcon.size());
```

What do you guys think? Any advice? Please limit answers to SDL2. I'm not using OpenGL.

I'm also interested in simple ways to offset vectors of SDL_Point so that I can do away with actorRect altogether, but I figure I'll probably want to nest viewports again later, so that's the question I'm asking.

ETA: I added the following code to find out the locations of those items on screen:

```
SDL_Rect myRect;
SDL_RenderGetViewport(gRenderer, &myRect);
printf("Viewport h,w,x,y: %i,%i,%i,%i\n", myRect.h,myRect.w,myRect.x,myRect.y);
for(int i = 0; i < mStickmanIcon.size(); i++)
{
    printf("stickman i,x,y: %i,%i,%i\n", i,mStickmanIcon.data()[i].x, mStickmanIcon.data()[i].y);
}
```

Here's the output:

```
stickman i,x,y: 0,5,15
stickman i,x,y: 1,8,12
stickman i,x,y: 2,11,15
stickman i,x,y: 3,8,12
stickman i,x,y: 4,8,9
stickman i,x,y: 5,5,9
stickman i,x,y: 6,11,9
stickman i,x,y: 7,8,9
stickman i,x,y: 8,8,6
stickman i,x,y: 9,7,6
stickman i,x,y: 10,5,4
stickman i,x,y: 11,5,2
stickman i,x,y: 12,7,0
stickman i,x,y: 13,8,0
stickman i,x,y: 14,11,2
stickman i,x,y: 15,11,4
stickman i,x,y: 16,9,6
Viewport h,w,x,y: 16,16,247,119
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'd try checking `mStickmanIcon.data()` to see what it's returning. It could be that the viewport is correct, but the stickman's points are drawing it way off in the wrong direction. `SDL_RenderGetViewport` might also be helpful if you think the viewport might be nesting wrong.

Comment: @NickReed Thanks Nick. I updated the question with some code and the output. Is that what you meant?

Comment: It is. Looks like your viewport is indeed a 16x16 square, but it looks like its x, y coordinates of 247,199 are misplaced at the top left area of the screen. Check and see if the viewport dimensions match where you're drawing your rect - it looks like it should be on the right side of the screen. Are you attaching to the right object?

Comment: @NickReed Yeah, so 274,199 are relative coordinates inside the "Layers" viewport. The "actorRect" renders in the correct location, but then when I set actorRect as the current viewport and try to render the stickman in it, it acts like actorRect isn't nested, and it renders the stickman relative to the window.

Comment: I believe that's the problem - nesting viewports might not be supported in that way. You'd likely want to set your viewports on absolute coordinates instead of relative ones - maybe get the coordinates of your current viewport before you change it, and then add those coordinates to the new viewport position?

Comment: @NickReed Yeah, the more I'm looking into this, the more I'm thinking you're right about that. SDL2 might just not support that. If you put it in an answer, I'll pick your answer... unless someone else comes along and says there's a way to do it ;P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through SDL, it doesn't seem like it's easily possible to nest viewports. You're in luck, though - since you've already got an existing viewport, as well as a rectangle you've just drawn, why not use that rectangle's coordinates as the base for your new viewport?

```cpp
//vector mStickmanIcon = {/*...a bunch of points...*/};
SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &Layers);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 200,250,165,255);
SDL_RenderFillRect(gRenderer, &actorRect);

SDL_Rect actorView;
actorView.x = Layers.x + actorRect.x;
actorView.y = Layers.y + actorRect.y;
actorView.w = actorRect.w;
actorView.h = actorRect.h;

SDL_RenderSetViewport(gRenderer, &actorView);
SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gRenderer, 0,0,0,255);
SDL_RenderDrawLines(gRenderer, mStickmanIcon.data(), mStickmanIcon.size());
```

Comment: More productive than what I expected! Many thanks, Mr. Reed.